# Using Backbone.Marionette, why can I not reference @ui elements when creating a new instance of a view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have created a simple view, `MyView`, that extends from `ItemView`. Then when I create the instance of `MyView`, I am trying to add references to UI elements within the view as well as events that use those UI elements.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="my-template">
    <p>This is a rendered template.</p>
  <button data-ui="changeModelNameButton">Change Model Name</button>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
// Define a custom view that extends off of ItemView
var MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#my-template"
});

// Instantiate the custom view we defined above
var view = new MyView({
  el: "#container",

  ui: {
    changeModelNameButton: '[data-ui~=changeModelNameButton]'
  },

  events: {
    'click @ui.changeModelNameButton': function() {
      alert('here'); 
    }
  }
});

// Render the view in the element defined within the custom view instantiation method
view.render();
```

I am receiving the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeModelNameButton' of
>   undefined

I noticed that if I move the ui declarations to the view definition, it works fine, but I would like to know why I can't add those when I create the instance. Is there no way to add them to the instance or am I missing something?

**Note: I am using Backbone 1.3.3, Marionette 2.4.4, Underscore 1.8.3, and jQuery 3.1.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Options overriding view's properties

Not all the options are automatically overriding the view class properties when passed on instantiation.

`ui` looks like it's not one of them.

Backbone will automatically apply the following (private) [`viewOptions`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/4a02b5fc3d9759ed8d3180b37cd982c8b30f8696/backbone.js#L1325-L1326) on a view:

```
// List of view options to be set as properties.
var viewOptions = [
    'model', 
    'collection', 
    'el', 
    'id', 
    'attributes', 
    'className', 
    'tagName', 
    'events'
];
```

In the view constructor, `this` is extended with the chosen options ([source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/4a02b5fc3d9759ed8d3180b37cd982c8b30f8696/backbone.js#L1317)):

```
_.extend(this, _.pick(options, viewOptions));
```

## How to pass the `ui` option?

You either need to put the `ui` hash in the view class definition, or to apply the ui hash yourself.

```
var MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#my-template",
    initialize: function(options) {

        // merge the received options with the default `ui` of this view.
        this.ui = _.extend({}, this.ui, this.options.ui);
    }
});
```

Note that options passed to a view are [available in `this.options` automatically](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/4cd2f9b51838a3d80b769f3bb5eef053b3e4448f/src/view.js#L35-L37).

---

## What's the real goal behind this?

If you're going to mess around the `ui` and the `events` with its callbacks, **it would be best to define a new view.**

It looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where the real problem lies in the architecture of the app, but we can't help since you're asking about what's blocking you right now.